# how to access dom element using iframe for different domain url

Tags: iframe

I want to get unique id of remoter url webpage which is inserted in iframe 
its working fine for local file eg aboutus.html (same domain) in all other browser but Chrome 
its not working in any of the browser for remote url of different domain for eg http://www.shopping.com

MainPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*"> 
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_show").click(function(){
            if($("#txt_url").val() == "") {
                alert("Enter URL");
                $("#txt_url").focus();
                }
            else 
            {
                var curUrl = $("#txt_url").val();
                $('#myframe').attr('src',$("#txt_url").val());
                windows.frames['#myframe'].location.reload();
                }
    });

    $('#btn-clear').click(function(){
        var htmlTxt = document.getElementById("unique_sel_textbox");
        $(htmlTxt).val(''); 
    });   


    $("#btn-inspect").click(function(){
        var iframeDoc = document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow; 
        $(iframeDoc).mouseover(function(event){
            $(event.target).css("outline","dashed 1px #000");  //addClass("set_outline");  
            }).mouseout(function(event){
                $(event.target).css("outline",""); //removeClass("set_outline");   
                }).click(function(event){
                    $(event.target).css("border","0.1em solid #f00"); //addClass("outline-selected"); 
                    var uniqSel=""; var curId="";   var curCls=""; var pasteCls="";
                    var pastePath = ""; 
                    var html_txt_Id = document.getElementById('unique_sel_textbox');
                    /*if(((event.target).id) && ((event.target).className)){
                            var mergIdCls = '#' + ((event.target).id) + '.' + ((event.target).className);
                            alert(mergIdCls); 
                        }
                    else */

                    if((event.target).id){
                         if(((event.target).id) == 'undefined')
                            curId="";
                        else
                            { 
                             curId = '#' + ((event.target).id);
                             html_txt_Id.value += " " + curId;
                             } 
                    }
                    else
                    if((event.target).className){ 
                        if(((event.target).className) ==  'undefined')
                            curCls = "";
                        else { 
                            var nodName = ((event.target).nodeName).toLowerCase();
                            curCls = '.' + ((event.target).className);
                            html_txt_Id.value += " " + nodName + curCls;
                             } 
                    }
                    else {
                    var curPath = getElementUniqueId(event.target); 
                    html_txt_Id.value += curPath;
                        } 
                });

                $( "#btn-inspect").unbind("click");  
    }); 
});

//get Dom Path of selected element 
function getElementUniqueId(element){
    return $(element).parent().andSelf().map(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var tagName = this.nodeName; 
        if($this.siblings(tagName).length >= 0){
            tagName += ":nth-child(" + ($(this).prevAll(tagName).length + 1) + ")"; 
            }
        return tagName; 
    }).get().join(" > ").toLowerCase();
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="main-wrap"> 
<div class="header" style="text-align:center; height:50px;"> 
    <h2> 
        DOM UNIQUE ID 
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="main-content"> 
    <div class="left-panel" style="width:250px; float:left; margin:10px; text-align:center;"> 
        <div class="enter-url"> 
            <form id="frm-url" style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:4px;">
                <br> <br> 
                <p> Enter URL </p>
                <input type="text" id="txt_url" style="width:170px">    
                <br> <br> 
                <input type="button" value=" Show " id="btn_show"/>     
                <br> <br>
            </form>
        </div>

        <br /> 

        <div class="html-element"> 
            <form>
                <p> HTML Elementes </p> 
                <textarea cols="25" rows="10" name="console" id="unique_sel_textbox" readonly="readonly" style="resize:none;"> </textarea>
                <br /> 
                <br /> 
                <input type="button" value=" Clear " id="btn-clear";/>  
                <input type="button" value=" Inspect " id="btn-inspect";/> 
            </form>
        </div>        

    </div> 
    <div class="right-panel"> 
            <iframe width="900" editable="true" frameborder="1" height="500" id="myframe" src="aboutUs.html"> </iframe>

            <br /> <br />
            <p> <b> Please Select and element and Get XPath of Highlighted Element </b>
            </p>
    </div> 
</div>

    <div class="footer" style="height:50px;"> 


    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

aboutUs.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title id="Page_Title">Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:150px; border:1px solid #999"> 
        <div style="height:80px; border:1px solid #999; margin:5px;"> 
            <div class="class-child" style="height:50px; margin:5px;  border:1px solid #999;">  div - 1 </div>
        </div>    
    </div> 

    <div style="height:50px; border:1px solid #666"> 
    div - 2 
    </div> 

    <div class="class-child" style="height:50px; border:1px solid #333"> 
    div - 3 
    </div> 

    <div> 
    <h3 id="heading - 3"> Heading - 3 </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="divClassTest" style="height:50px; margin:5px; border:1px solid #333" >
        Testing Div class 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

if i use remote url in iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" its not working

Help me how I can resolve this issues/guide me which technology i have to use if anybody knows about it.

by 
Timothy

Comment: Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: It looks like you're only using the iframe's `contentWindow` in order to hook up a `mouseover` event, and use the `event.target` for styling. Why not just connect to the `iframe` itself to avoid hitting the Same Origin Policy restriction?

Comment: Sorry. I am not getting you So please explain in details

Comment: Your `mouseover` event is hooked up with this line: `$(iframeDoc).mouseover(function(event){`. Try hooking it up to `#myframe` (the iframe itself) directly, instead of the internal `contentWindow` object: `$('#myframe').mouseover(function(event){`.

Comment: I want to fetch the external webpage elements. i tried it $('#myframe').mouseover(function(event){ its target only the iframe not the contents of external webpage element. please check it in FireFox with aboutus.html as iframe content so you will understand what exactly i want to. pls help me. Thanks you.